# What are the differences between starttable and startTABLE?

Tags: tables, context

Consider the following :

```
\starttable[|c|c|]
\NC a \NC b \NC\SR
\stoptable
```

It won't compile if I switch to `\startTABLE`.  On the other hand, the following won't compile if I switch to `starttable` :

```
\startTABLE
\NC a \NC b \NC\NR
\stopTABLE
```

(it will compile if I replace only `\stopTABLE` with `\stoptable`, though…).

Indeed, `\starttable` needs arguments and `\startTABLE` doesn't understand `\SR`.  Also, there are noticeable differences between the displayed results.

Is this expected ?  If so, most web search engines not being case sensitive, are difference between `\starttable` and `\startTABLE` documented somewhere ?

Comment: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Tables_Overview may help.  It appears `\starttable` is older and perhaps deprecated.

Comment: I was just reading this indeed.  Also http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Table vs http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\starttable` loads the old macro based on \TeX\ 's \TaBlE, which is outdated.

`\startTABLE` calls the modern and more *ConTeXT'way* module **natural table**.

That's all.

Comment: There is an even more advanced macro for tables in context: [xtables or extreme tables](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/xtables).